# Create a countdown timer on button click when value is entered in text box : Javascript

Tags: javascript

I meet a problem like when I try to enter a number like 30, and count it down until 0, but it doesn't work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>123</title>
<script type="text/javascript">



function startTimer()
{

   seconds = seconds - 1;
   if (seconds <= 0)    
   {
      seconds = 0;
   }
    else
        {
            seconds--;
        }

   var obj = document.getElementById("timer");
   obj.display.value= seconds;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="timer" action="#">
<p><input type="text" name="display" size="
    20" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Start"
    onclick="Id=setInterval('startTimer()', 100)" />
</form>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is in if else statement, I am not sure if I make the user input correct.

Comment: Are you expecting the counter to do 30 days/mins/seconds ?

Comment: I am expecting the counter to do seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign 'seconds' to the current value of obj.display.value at he start of startTimer()  and make sure to give the seconds input a 'number' type and a starting value.

Also use clearInterval(Id)  to stop the timer once its finished..

```js
function startTimer()
{
   var obj = document.getElementById("timer");

    /* make sure to tell javascript that 'seconds' is  Number that 
        comes from the input box */
   var seconds;


   seconds = Number(obj.display.value);

/*  Don't need this *AND* seconds-- */
//       seconds = seconds - 1;

   if (seconds <= 0)    
   {
   clearInterval(Id);
      seconds = 0;
   }
    else
        {
            seconds--;
        }

  obj.display.value = seconds;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>123</title>
<script type="text/javascript">




</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="timer" action="#">
<p><input type="number" name="display"  size="
    20" value="30" /></p>

<!-- changed the interval from 100ms to 1000ms -->
<p><input type="button" value="Start"
    onclick="Id=setInterval('startTimer()', 1000)" />
</form>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is simple but easy to let me understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

modify the number to whatever you want, if you want an `input` control then I assume you know how to do it, if not let me know.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var inputVal =  document.getElementById('myInput').value;
 var seconds = inputVal, $seconds = document.querySelector('#countdown');
 (function countdown() {
       $seconds.textContent = seconds + ' second' + (seconds == 1 ?  '' :  's')
       if(seconds --> 0) setTimeout(countdown, 1000)
   })();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter number..." >
<button onclick="myFunction()">Start Counter</button>  
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't know how to let input control.

Comment: @LiteMelody I have updated my answer, when users selects number in the input box you will get the counter down time, hope it works for you. Let me know

Comment: Yes it really helped me to understand, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LiteMelody is this what you looking for? can you look into this and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

asign **seconds** at the top of the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
seconds =100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I want to let the user input the value.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" id="inp">
<div id="counter"></div>
<script>
let input = document.getElementById('inp')
let counter = document.getElementById('counter')

let handleInput = e => {
 let num = Number(e.target.value)
 let _counter = num - 1
 let timer = setInterval(_ => {
 if(!_counter)
   clearInterval(timer)
  counter.innerText =  _counter
  _counter--
 }, 1000)
}
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput)
</script>
```

The above logic works for 1 - 9 (single-digit input), you can add a debounce if you want to go for double-digit or greater numbers

Comment: Thanks for the comment, appreciate!